# ArcGIS Python how to get service name from the .msd file?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server

How to get the service name from the .msd file on ArcGIS server using Python, the sample below from the Stack Overflow display how to get the layer name from the .msd file.

```
import zipfile
from xml.etree.cElementTree import iterparse

zz = zipfile.ZipFile('C:\\Temp\\Untitled.msd')

serviceNames = []
for name in zz.namelist():
    if name == "DocumentInfo.xml" or name == "layers/layers.xml":
        pass
    else:
        for _event, elem in iterparse(zz.open(name)):
            if elem.tag == "Name":
                serviceNames.append(elem.text)
                break
zz.close()
```

Is there any way of retrieving the service name?

Comment: `.msd` files are extinct, having been replaced with `.sddraft` and `.sd` at ArcGIS Server 10.1.

Comment: Okay is there any way to get the service name from the .sddraft or .sd file by using python (arcpy)

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to make fundamental changes. You should always include the exact version of software in use and your best effort towards a solution within the question.